# Studying computing on HSE06 in VASP

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, software, density-of-states, optical-properties

I optimized the structure in PBE. Can anyone help me with HSE06 to calculate the optics and DOS of the material from this step? I would be grateful if you could write step by step.

Comment: For 'optics', are you interested in the dielectric tensor? Examples can be found [here](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Optical_properties_and_dielectric_response_-_Tutorial) from the VASP Wiki. For the DOS, the VASP Wiki has a tutorial [here](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Fcc_Si_DOS). HSE06 tutorials on the VASP Wiki can be found [here](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/NiO_HSE06) and [here](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Si_HSE_bandstructure). You can click on the INCAR settings in these pages to understand what they do, and combine appropriately for your use case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculation of DOS in HSE06](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9881/calculation-of-dos-in-hse06)

Comment: @CWTan I'd like if you could write that comment as an answer. Otherwise we'll close the question.

Comment: @NikeDattani Sure, I'll write an answer. I wrote the comment just because I didn't think they were the "step-by-step" instructions that OP wanted.

Comment: @CWTan thanks. Usually I'd agree with you, but in this case the question will he closed if it doesn't have an answer, and OP probably prefers an answer without the step-by-step part, versus getting no answer at all :)

Answer (score 4):

As per my comment,

- If OP is referring to dielectric tensor for "optics", examples can be found [here](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Optical_properties_and_dielectric_response_-_Tutorial) from the VASP Wiki.
- For the density-of-states (DOS), the VASP Wiki has a tutorial [here](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Fcc_Si_DOS).
- HSE06 tutorials on the VASP Wiki can be found [here](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Si_HSE_bandstructure) and [here](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/NiO_HSE06).
- HSE06 DOS tutorial can be found [here](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Fcc_Ni_DOS_with_hybrid_functional).

I suggested that OP can click on the INCAR settings in these pages to understand what they do, and combine them appropriately for OP's specific use case of HSE06 DOS calculations.

I'll also give a more "step-by-step" answer, with the caveat that this is just one possible way of doing things that makes sense to me.

1. Structure relaxation with PBE

We could have done the structure relaxation with HSE06 but that's going to be very expensive. Use the `CONTCAR` from the PBE structure relaxation as the `POSCAR` for all subsequent steps.

2. Static PBE calculation (optional)

I would suggest performing a static calculation with PBE to generate a `WAVECAR` file (set `LWAVE = .TRUE.`). I believe that starting the HSE06 calculation with the PBE converged orbitals should speed up convergence.

3. HSE06 DOS

For the actual HSE06 calculation, you'd want these `INCAR` settings, which can be found in VASP Wiki's HSE06 tutorials linked above. Of course, some of them can be tweaked accordingly.

```
  LHFCALC  = .TRUE. ! Hartree-Fock / DFT hybrid
  ALGO     = Damped
  TIME     = 0.5
  HFSCREEN = 0.2    ! HSE06
  AEXX     = 0.25   ! fraction of exact exchange
```

If you did the previous step of getting a PBE converged `WAVECAR`, move it to the directory for this HSE06 calculation. It should be detected when you
start the calculation, but you could explicitly set `ISTART=1` for certainty.

For the DOS, include in the `INCAR` file `ISMEAR = -5` (the tetrahedron method), which is important for getting high-quality DOS (see [here](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/ISMEAR) and this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S277294942200002X?via%3Dihub)), and `LORBIT = 11`  to generate `DOSCAR` and `PROCAR` files.

If OP wants practice, it looks like the files can be downloaded for this [example](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Fcc_Ni_DOS_with_hybrid_functional) from the VASP Wiki (near the bottom of the page).